# The @RelationshipEntity is not fulfill after 2 step

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm very new with neo4j and spring-data-neo4j. I created time tree as this post:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/

And I create my entity like this:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "User")
public class User extends GraphEntity {
    @Autowired
    private DayRepository dayRepository;

    @Property(name = "account")
    private String account;

    @Property(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Relationship(type = "BIRTH_ON", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Day birthday;

getter and setter
}
```

Because of time tree so I create @NodeEntity for Day, Month, Year:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Day")
public class Day extends SimpleEntity {
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_DAY", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private HasDay hasDay;
    public HasDay getHasDay() {
        return this.hasDay;
    }
    public void setHasDay(final HasDay hasDay) {
        this.hasDay = hasDay;
    }
}

@NodeEntity(label = "Month")
public class Month extends SimpleEntity {
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_MONTH", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private HasMonth hasMonth;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_DAY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<HasDay> hasDays;
}

@NodeEntity(label = "Year")
public class Year extends SimpleEntity {
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_YEAR", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private HasYear hasYear;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_MONTH", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<HasMonth> hasMonths;
}
```

And @RelationShipEntity for them:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_DAY")
public class HasDay extends SimpleEntity {
    @StartNode
    private Month month;
    @EndNode
    private Day day;
}
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_MONTH")
public class HasMonth extends SimpleEntity {
    @StartNode
    private Year year;
    @EndNode
    private Month month;
}
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_YEAR")
public class HasYear extends SimpleEntity {
    @StartNode
    private TimeLine timeLine;
    @EndNode
    private Year year;
}
```

And GraphRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    @Override
    @Query("MATCH p=(u:User)-[b:BIRTH_ON]->(d:Day)<-[hd:HAS_DAY]-(m:Month)<-[hm:HAS_MONTH]-(y:Year)<-[hy:HAS_YEAR]-(t:TimeLine) WHERE ID(u)= {0} RETURN p")
    User findOne(Long id);
}
```

I ran my test and got User correctly with the Day is correct, the relationship HasDay and it's Month is fullfill but Month's relationship HasMonth is null. I don't know what the problem.

Comment: What version of Neo4j, Spring Data Neo4j and OGM are you using?

Comment: When you write a `@RelationshipEntity` you are already specifying the `type` and `direction` (using `@StartNode` and `@EndNode`). You don't need to mark anything other than that it's a `Relationship` on the classes `Day`, `Month` and `Year`.

Comment: @digx1 I'm using spring data neo4j v4, and i use repository. I write my code again, it look like my problem is the wrong import of TimeLine